# sed removal of whitespace

Tags: sed, perl, whitespace

I find that `sed` often fails to pattern-match whitespace. Consider the following examples:

```
echo 'A     B     C' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
ABC

echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
A       B       C

perl -e 'print "A     B     C\n"' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
ABC

perl -e 'print "A\tB\tC\n"' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
A       B       C
```

Could someone please explain why `sed` sometimes fails to match whitespace?

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu 11.10 / sed 4.2.1 like @Peter also said. What is the system you use? sed version? environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
A       B       C
```

Works for me

```
$ echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g'
ABC
```

Try this

```
$ echo -e 'a\tb' | sed -e 's/[ \t]//'
ab
```

2.

```
perl -e 'print "A     B     C\n"' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//g'
A       B       C
```

your string doesn't contain a space at the start (`^`) of the line

Comment: Thank you. I removed the stray ^ anchor. How else can I match a tab character?

Comment: Thank you. Removing the * multiplier (`echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | sed 's/[ \t]//g'`) did not work.

Comment: @user001: `echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | perl -pe 's/[ \t]*//g'` :-)

Comment: Oh, that works wonderfully. Thank you so much. Any idea why the `perl` script works but the `awk` script fails? They appear identical.

Comment: @user001: I don't know why your sed doesn't work. It seems broken. Maybe something in the environment is triggering some feature.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of `sed` don't support `\t` and some other escapes on the left hand side of a substitution command.

You can find information on variations among versions of `sed` in the [FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/editor-faq/sed/).

Answer (score 0):

The second statement you have above works on my machine (Ubuntu 10.10 amd64, sed ver 4.2.1, sed package version 4.2.1-7) and I don't really have an explanation as to why that one wouldn't work.

The third and fourth are because you are using the beginning-of-line anchor (^), so it would *only* strip the leading whitespace and in your input text, you don't have any whitespace at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: I forgot to remove the BOL anchor (^). Even if it is removed, the fourth statement fails to work. Post amended.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **\s** to match both whitespace and tab:

```
echo 'A     B     C' | sed 's/\s//g'
ABC

echo -e 'A\tB\tC' | sed 's/\s//g'
ABC

perl -e 'print "A     B     C\n"' | sed 's/\s//g'
ABC

perl -e 'print "A\tB\tC\n"' | sed 's/\s//g'
ABC
```